# Gnat Pro Cross compiling

Tags: linux, arm, ada, toolchain, gnat

I am trying to use gnat pro as a cross compiler which use arm-eabi toolchain, but it cannot recognize any Ada packages!!

Here is compilation result:

```
    5:6 "ada.calendar" is not a predefined library unit
    2:6 "ada.direct_io" is not a predefined library unit
    8:6 "ada.float_text_io" is not a predefined library unit
    7:6 "ada.integer_text_io" is not a predefined library unit
    10:6 "ada.numerics" is not a predefined library unit
    2:6 "ada.text_io" is not a predefined library unit
    2:6 "bmp (spec)" depends on "ada.direct_io (spec)"
    2:6 "bmp (spec)" depends on "ada.text_io (spec)"
    3:6 "serial_net (spec)" depends on "gnat.sockets (spec)"
    2:6 "stream (body)" depends on "bmp (spec)"
    3:6 "stream (body)" depends on "serial_net (spec)"
    3:6 file "g-socket.ads" not found
```

Comment: Do you have an RTS built and installed for the target? You may need `-RTS=...` compile options to point to it. Haven't used Gnat Pro myself so can't be more specific.

Comment: If you’re using GNAT Pro, you should have a support contract. AdaCore are very good at support (it’s how they make their living), you should use them. In any case, you should show your code and the command line.